# How to change the onscreen button

Tags: android, on-screen-keyboard

I looked for the question everywhere on the Internet but can't find the answer. What I found is to hide the whole button tray all together.

When the keyboard is down, the button is shown as in the picture.
[image]

But when the keyboard is showing the icon changes to -

[image]

My problem is to change the button (as in the second image), when my emoticons are showing. So, is there any way by which I can programatically change the button on an event and change it back on another event?

Comment: Do you mean http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int) ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible yet. Perhaps this will be implemented in later versions of Android.

Not all devices have an onscreen navigation bar, a lot of devices still have hardware buttons.
Nevertheless, you'll might find this article interesting: http://arpitonline.com/blog/2014/07/27/improving-androids-navigationbar/

Comment: How does Whatsapp do it. Since it has the same button when the emoji keyboard is showing.

Comment: there is no emoticon keyboard actually, its just a view. Android does not recognize it as a keyboard. You can try creating a custom keyboard, but I can't help you any further with that

Comment: It cannot be a keyboard (in whatsapp), since if it was a keyboard. The system would've asked me to change keyboard (in language and input settings). It is the default keyboard.